# Visual Studio 2013 Preview Native C++ Edit and Continue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Has anyone been able to use [Edit and Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf(v=vs.120).aspx) with Visual Studio 2013 Preview and a C++ native application (either 32 or 64 bit)?

After making a simple console application, setting a breakpoint, then making any type of change:

```
Edit and Continue : error 1002 : Data symbol has changed
```

This MSDN page suggests it should work, and I've done everything I think I need to do, such as enabling native Edit and Continue in Tools->Options->Debugging->Edit and Continue
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esaeyddf(v=vs.120).aspx

I have no problems with it working in VS 2012. I realize it is a "preview", but I'd be surprised if it is simply broken without any comment. At least a better error could be displayed, such as "not yet enabled in preview".

All my googling shows comments about E&C being added for 64bit managed apps, but nothing about native. I tested a simple managed app, and it works there.

Comment: Funny, I just tried it a few hours ago and couldn't get it working either, but I never used Edit and Continue anyway in C++ so I thought I'm probably doing something wrong... +1

Comment: Glad it's not just me :) E&C has worked for native C/C++ in Visual Studio for a lot of years. You do have to turn it on for native apps, but then it works great (at least in VS 2012 and earlier).

Comment: Yup I just tried it out in VS 2008 and it was pretty amazing.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll answer my own question. After submitting a bug report [HERE](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794660/visual-studio-2013-preview-native-c-edit-and-continue-broken), someone from the VC++ team responded and said it was a known issue in the VS 2013 Preview, and it will be fixed in the final release.

So that is good news for C++ and Visual Studio. I think Edit and Continue is a huge feature for Visual Studio, and it's nice to know it will continue to work for native C++.

Comment: But from what I've read, it only works on 32-bit native apps, not 64-bit ones, right?

Comment: I don't know and can't test, since native E&C is totally broken in the preview. I guess we'll have to wait for the release to find out. I'm afraid I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work for x64, in which case expect some lame excuses and vague suggestions it might work in VS 2014.